# База данных Oracle

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Я установил на Виндовс Oracle Database Express 21c через установщик в архиве с офф. сайта. Захожу в браузер на страницу с БД. Ввожу имя, пароль (тут ошибки точно нет) и контейнер. В качестве контейнера я пробовал вводить название БД - oracle, которое я сделал при установке. Там еще было какое-то Pluggable name - orclpdb, его тоже пробовал. Выводится бесконечно доп окно с авторизацией. Пробовал писать CDB$ROOT в качестве контейнера, не помогло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]